# Multiple entitlement in ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

When archiving app all viewcontrollers are display as executable. Also not able to upload app to app store.
How to remove viewcontroller as executable in ios app.

[image: view controller as executable]


When uploading via "Application loader" it show error as "ERROR ITMS-90171: Invalid Bundle structure" for all these viewcontrollers.

[image: uploading to app store]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove some file from build phase

Comment: Thanks after removing all viewcontrollers and .xib files form build phase-> copy bundle resources this issue resolved.